# TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: str, how to edit the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, input

I was checking out the The Last Stone Weight problem and I wanted to have an input section where I input the weights of the stones. I tried:
'''

```
import heapq

stones = [input('input: ')] 

def LastStoneWeight(self, stones):
    stones = [-i for i in stones] #the error is here
    heapq.heapify(stones)

    while len(stones) > 1:
        new = heapq.heappop(stones) - heapq.heappop(stones)
        if new != 0:
        heapq.heappush(stones, new)
return -stones[0] if stones else 0

print('%s' %LastStoneWeight(stones, stones))
```

'''

But the error occurred. Can u guys help me. Thanks a lot:D

Comment: What is the error? Was it working before you had the input section?

Comment: `stones` is a string, presumably something like `"1 2 3"`. You need to turn that into a list of `int` values first, e.g. `[int(x) for x in stones.split()]`.

Comment: `input()` returns a string value.  If you want it to be an integer, you'll have to convert it.

Comment: Lmao guys thanks. It worked. I fixed that line to '''[-int(x) for x in stones.split()]''' and it worked fine. Thanks a lot, I'm a beginner and your help means alot:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are applying the minus sign ('-') to a variable of type string.

If you are expecting a number, you could cast the input as an int.

```py
stones = [int(input('input: '))]
```